# Break a table row into multiple line (responsive layout)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a webpage that lists items. The default template uses a table for that, which i find very appropriate. In this table however, there is one column that contains much more text than the others:

[image]

While that works out on a large screen, it is very annoying to read on a small screen:

[image]

In order to use the available space better, I can only think of a fake-table layout using divs. I did a prototype, using bootstrap grid layout, that looks like a table row on large screens, but has a different layout on small and extra small screens:

[image]

While that improves the readability of the text by using the full width, I cannot use the utilities I've got for tables any more, and it breaks the user experience in subtle ways. For example, I use a nice script that enables sorting at the client. But that works only on real tables. (Also, there are small inconsistencies and visual differences between real tables and fake tables)

Is there any way that I can reformat a table row into a multi-line container similar to the one in the last image?

FYI: I am using jquery 2.1.1, Bootstrap 3.2.0.1 as GUI Framework and asp.net MVC on the server.

Bootply is here: http://www.bootply.com/pRehwTai4G

Edit: in case that did not come out clear enough: I want to keep the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags but style them similar to the divs. I do not want to replace the table with divs.

Comment: if you post a bootply with the problem i have a few ideas; but none that i can say for sure.

Comment: What about this: http://www.bootply.com/kA1JWPSFSz -- you'll need to adjust the CSS but this plugin is sweet

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could take a look at [Responsive data tables](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/). If that does not suit your needs, you could use JavaScript to re-create your table views as divs. This would be the easiest if you can get table data as JSON, which would be transformed into either tables or divs - depending on resolution. If you can't have it as JSON, you can always use jQuery's html() or text() to get the data from table cells and re-draw into divs.

Comment: Just a note from more modern times: I think this answer aged very well over time. If you want different layouts on narrow screens, I'd say it is best to do them both separately and  choose between them client side. This works with really little JS even.
The most upvoted answer ist very nice ffor the lack of JS but it feels a bit hacky to re-define tr and you will fight the browser if you want to make the table rows into nicer panels to have 1-n data pieces per row (as in the last image in the question)

Answer (score 52):

You can do this purely with a couple of lines of css...

```
    @media all and (max-width:768px) {
        .calculator tr {    display: table;  width:100%;    }               
        .calculator td {    display: table-row; }           
    }
```

.calculator is the class used for the table:

```
<table class="calculator">
```

I use this to quickly alter the table that I use for calculator inputs for smarter looking design when viewing between mobile/desktop: [live example here](http://www.icalculator.info/tax_calculator/2017.html) though the difference is best viewed by a mobile device and desktop along side each other (not all my mobile scripts are delived to the desktop browser so the overall design may look odd if you purely view through a desktop browser and minimise but the cells will become rows etc. to illustrate).

In addition you could add a span / label etc within the cell and makes this

```
display:table-cell;
```

and make the table a block if you prefer, this approach is much more lightweight and stops the necessity to use javascript.

Comment: Best answer here!

Comment: After trying (and failing) to solve the problem of responsive tables using bootstrap and flexbox, this was the solution that saved me

Comment: Also noticed that when you are using bootstrap, setting display: table-row makes the <td> scale down to the content size. If you want a full width td (like a row) display: block worked for me

Comment: The bootstrap effect will be due to css setup, you could override by applying an additional class to the table and targeting that way if needed.

Comment: brilliant solution!

Answer (score 13):

If you remove `thead` tag from your table and bind `th` inside `tbody`, then you can use the following jquery with css code to get responsive tables:

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-sm-1">Col 1
            </th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Col 2
            </th>
            <th class="col-sm-6">Col 3
            </th>
            <th class="col-sm-1">Col 4
            </th>
            <th class="col-sm-1">Col 5
            </th>
            <th class="col-sm-1">Col 6
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ILK-AK Garching
            </td>
            <td>Einen guten Titel zu finden ist eigentlich eine Diskussion …
            </td>
            <td>Eine wunderbare Heiterkeit hat meine ganze Seele eingenommen, gleich den süßen Frühlingsmorgen, die ich mit ganzem Herzen genieße. Ich bin allein und…
            </td>
            <td>Niedrig
            </td>
            <td>
                <time datetime="2014-07-18T12:03:38.9570000">18.07.2014 12:03</time>
            </td>
            <td>
                <time datetime="2014-08-20T14:15:39.3830000">20.08.2014 14:15</time>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ILK-AK Garching
            </td>
            <td>Zeta-Kafka ist, gleich einem Manifest, pompös und glorreich
            </td>
            <td>Jemand musste Josef K. verleumdet haben, denn ohne dass er etwas Böses getan hätte, wurde er eines Morgens verhaftet. »Wie ein Hund!« sagte er, es wa…
            </td>
            <td>Niedrig
            </td>
            <td>
                <time rel="timeago" datetime="2014-08-20T13:41:22.3500000">20.08.2014 13:41</time>
            </td>
            <td>
                <time rel="timeago" datetime="2014-08-20T14:16:39.8170000">20.08.2014 14:16</time>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ILK-AK Garching
            </td>
            <td>Tests von mechanischen Apparaten sind grundsätzlich erwünsc…
            </td>
            <td>Er hörte leise Schritte hinter sich. Das bedeutete nichts Gutes. Wer würde ihm schon folgen, spät in der Nacht und dazu noch in dieser engen Gasse mi…
            </td>
            <td>Mittel
            </td>
            <td>
                <time datetime="2014-08-20T13:41:51.0870000">20.08.2014 13:41</time>
            </td>
            <td>
                <time datetime="2014-08-20T14:18:21.2200000">20.08.2014 14:18</time>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
/* seo friendly tables */
 .div-table {
    display: table;
    /* Defines a Table */
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    color: #8d8d8d;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.table-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.table-head {
    display: table-header-group;
    /* Defines a table header group */
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
    color: #333;
    background: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    font-size: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.table-head .column {
    /* Column inside the table-head */
    background: #f2f2f2;
    color: #7d7d7d;
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
.table-row {
    display: table-row;
    /* Defines a table row */
    padding: 3px 6px;
    color: #333;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.table-row .column:nth-child(1) {
    /* First column in a row */
    border-left: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
.table-row:last-child .column {
    /* column in a last row */
    border-bottom: none;
}
.table-row:hover {
    background: #f9f9f9;
}
.column {
    display: table-cell;
    /* Defines a table cell */
    padding: 8px 3px;
    color: #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
/* Responsive table */
 @media all and (max-width:768px) {
    .div-table, .table-row, .column, .column:before {
        display: block;
        /* Converts a table, table row, table column and table column:before into a block element */
    }
    .div-table, .table-row .column:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    .table-head {
        position: absolute;
        /* Hides table head but not using display none */
        top: -1000em;
        left: -1000em;
    }
    .table-row {
        border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
    .table-row .column {
        border-right:none;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .table-row .column:nth-child(1) {
        /* first column of the row */
        border-left: none;
        border-right: none;
    }
    .table-row .column:last-child {
        /* last column of the row */
        border-right: none;
    }
    .table-row:last-child .column, .column {
        /* Column in the last row and column */
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    }
    .table-row:hover {
        background: #fff;
    }
    .column:before {
        /* prints the value of data-label attribute before the column data */
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-right: 20px;
        font-size: 12px;
        content:"" attr(data-label)"";
        /* call the attribute value of data-label and adds a string // */
    }
    .column:hover {
        background: #f9f9f9;
    }
}
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var gridClass = $('.table');
    // counts total number of td in a head so that we can can use it for label extraction
    var head_col_count = $(gridClass).find('tbody th').size();

    // loop which replaces td
    for (i = 0; i <= head_col_count; i++) {
        // head column label extraction
        var head_col_label = $(gridClass).find('tbody th:nth-child(' + i + ')').text();
        // replaces td with <div class="column" data-label="label">
        $(gridClass).find('tr td:nth-child(' + i + ')').replaceWith(function () {
            return $('<div class="column" data-label="' + head_col_label + '">').append($(this).contents());
        });
    }
    // replaces table with <div class="table">
    $(gridClass).replaceWith(function () {
        return $('<div class="div-table">').append($(this).contents());
    });

    // replaces thead with <div class="table-head">
    $('.div-table tbody tr:first-child').replaceWith(function () {
        return $('<div class="table-head">').append($(this).contents());
    });
    // replaces tbody with <div class="table-container">
    $('.div-table tbody').replaceWith(function () {
        return $('<div class="table-container">').append($(this).contents());
    });
    // replaces tr with <div class="table-row">
    $('.div-table tr').replaceWith(function () {
        return $('<div class="table-row">').append($(this).contents());
    });
    // replaces th with <div class="column">
    $('.div-table th').replaceWith(function () {
        return $('<div class="column">').append($(this).contents());
    });
});
```

A fullscreen demo can be found [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ravimallya/8xnSN/3/show/). Jsfiddle.net edit [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/8xnSN/3/).

However, if you wish to go with the current html markup, then, you have to change the script a bit.

Comment: Nice solution to this OP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Pete, I used your solution with a small modification. (using a class 'br' to break a row and continue with the TDs.)

```
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
.calculator br {display:none;width:0;} 
.calculator tr td.br {display:none} 

@media all and (max-width:768px) {
.calculator tr {display: table;width:100%;} 
.calculator td {width:50%;}           
.calculator th {width:50%;}
.calculator tr td.br {display:table-row;} 
.calculator tr th.br {display:table-row;}             
}
</style>


<table class="calculator" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
<th>Firstname a</th><th>Lastname</th>
<th class="br">Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jilldfs fds</td><td>Smith</td><td class="br"></td><td>50</td><td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td class="br"></td><td>94</td><td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```